# Erro de conexão smtp com C#(autenticado)

Tags: c#, smtp

Segue abaixo o Script utilizado ao tentar enviar ocorre um erro: Falha a uma chamada SSPI. o Cliente e o Servidor não podem se comunicar porque não possuem um algoritmo em comum.

```
string CorpoEmail = file;
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    // Endereco que irá aparecer no e-mail do usuário
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("email@email.com.br", "Fale Conosco");
    // Destinatarios do e-mail, para incluir mais de um basta separar por ponto e virgula
    mailMessage.To.Add(destinatario);
    mailMessage.Subject = assunto;
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    // Conteudo do corpo do e-mail
    mailMessage.Body = CorpoEmail.ToString();
    mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    //smtp do e-mail que irá enviar
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Host = "smtp.host.com.br";
    smtpClient.Port = 587;


    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    //credenciais da conta que utilizará para enviar o e-mail
    smtpClient.Credentials = new 
    NetworkCredential("email@email.com.br", "senha");
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    return true;
```

Comment: O erro não está no código, mas na comunicação entre o servidor onde a aplicação está rodando e o servidor smtp. Para ter certeza disso pode enviar um e-mail usando uma conta qualquer do gmail, por exemplo. Quanto a comunicação entre os computadores, por algum motivo o servidor deve estar barrando, será necessários mais informações sobre eles. Veja: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197582(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Estava realizando alguns testes aqui e fiz um exemplo com o Python usando a classe SMTP dele e conseguir realizar o Envio do e-mail será que tem alguma configuração que posso fazer no C# para conseguir enviar ?

Comment: Já tentou remover o Ssl pra fazer um teste? `smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;`

Comment: Sim, tentei ocorre outro erro dizendo que a conexão requer starttls, usando a porta 25 consigo enviar normalmente, só que preciso enviar pela porta segura do Servidor

Comment: Veja se algo [dessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449779/security-exception-port-587-smtppermission-email-send-by-gmail-in-asp-net-c-s/34450051#34450051) do SO ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente você esta tentando fazer uma chamada com SSL/TLS usando uma porta não segura (587), tente desativar a função SSL/TLS, para isso, substitua esse valor:

```
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Por esse:

```
smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema, se o erro persistir, verifique se o host esta correto e ativo em "smtpClient.Host".